# Camel, public static variables and processors

Tags: java, static, apache-camel, spring-camel

Into a camel processor, I have set two static vars with property names:

```
 public static final String CI_PROPERTY = "ci";
 public static final String IS_PDF_PROPERTY = "isPdf";
```

and I assign like:

```
 exchange.setProperty(CI_PROPERTY, documentProperties.get(MAP_PARAMETER_ATTACHMENT_URI));
 exchange.setProperty(IS_PDF_PROPERTY, documentProperties.get(MAP_PARAMETER_IS_PDF));
```

These names should be used in other processors to retrieve properties.

The question is: other processors have access to these names? Or I should move them to another class? In case, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that as you can be seen below:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class FooProcessor implements Processor {
    public static final String FOO_PROPERTY = "FOO";
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setProperty(FOO_PROPERTY, "This is a Foo property.");
    }
}
```

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class BarProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(exchange.getProperty(FooProcessor.FOO_PROPERTY, String.class));
    }
}
```

```
from("direct:mainRoute")
.routeId("MainRoute")
    .log("MainRoute BEGINS: BODY: ${body}")
    .process(new FooProcessor())
    .process(new BarProcessor())
    .log("MainRoute ENDS: BODY: ${body}")
.end()
;
```

When the route above will be run the following is logged as expected:

```
MainRoute BEGINS: BODY:
MainRoute ENDS: BODY: This is a Foo property.
```

However I don't think processors should have compile time (nor runtime) dependencies to other processors. As usual refactor the common parts to another class which is used by the processors.

Comment: Thanks! But setting the variable into one particular processor gives us information about where it's created, automatically... ;)

Comment: @Lore Sure - just consider the trade-offs! Also the scale matters - having 3 properties is different than having 30 properties.